# Button_Click() Event fires twice in windows desktop application

Tags: c#, events, desktop-application, buttonclick

I am creating a form in which search option is provided like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jP7k.png)

I am working in a MDI form application.

My code is :

```
 private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

    string query = null;
    if (txtBillNo.Enabled && txtBillNo.Text.Trim().Length != 0)
    {
        query = "Select BillNo,PartyName,City,State,FORMAT(BillDt,'dd-mm-yyyy')as Dt from BillMaster where BillNo=" + Convert.ToInt32(txtBillNo.Text.Trim());
        FillGrid(query);
    }
    else if (txtName.Enabled && txtName.Text.Trim().Length != 0)
    {
            query = "Select BillNo,PartyName,City,State,FORMAT(BillDt,'dd-mm-yyyy')as Dt from BillMaster where UCASE(PartyName) like '" + txtName.Text.Trim().ToUpper() + "'";
            FillGrid(query);
    }

    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter Value First");

        if (rdbName.Enabled)
        {
            txtName.Focus();

        }
        else if (rdbBillNo.Enabled)
        {
           txtBillNo.Focus();

        }

    }                 

}
```

The conditions are for checking whether the text boxes are left or not. If it is left blank then I am giving the message that user must enter the value. But when I am running the program it prompts twice, then I debugged the program and found that the `Click` event is called twice.

What should I do to tackle this problem.
Please help.

Comment: Did you register btnSearch.Click event more than one?

Comment: Do you call btnSearch_Click method when app loaded ?

Comment: maybe you registered to the event via dessiner and via your code?

Comment: Sir, I have registered the event in my `load()` event but not at design time.. @im_a_noob

Comment: No I have registered the btnSearch_Click() once only in the `Load()` of form @DavutGürbüz

Answer (score 2):

In WPF you have to set e.Handled to True after `FillGrid(query)` 
In win forms, delete and dont register btnSearch.Click in Load()

Comment: I am not finding `Handled` in my Button_Click() @Mustafa Ekici

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio Open CallStack and find out which function call Click event while debugging.

`Debug->Windows->Call Stack`

Comment: i think duplicated events are overwrited not added

Comment: The click event works without saying its handled. I think it could be double registration for click event or an other call from FillGrid. The only way is inspecting Call Stack.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a WPF project make sure you don't have the click Handler registered in XAML and the project's C# code. I had the same issue and it was due to this reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think the method signature might need to be changed to use **RoutedEventArgs e**

Then, at the end of the method body, you can set **e.Handled to True**

```
     private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    // do some stuff  
    e.Handled = True

}
```